# QR-code decoding using python got too many values to unpack error

Tags: python, decode, qr-code

I was generating a QR code image using python.

My code:

```
import qrcode
data = 'Authenticated'

img = qrcode.make(data)

img.save('trademark.jpg')
```

After that, I wanted to fetch the information from my own generated QR code. For the above code, it would give output like name Authenticated and other information like height of the QRcode etc.

My code for fetching data of QR code:

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image

decode_image = ("trademark.jpg")

result = decode(decode_image)
```

I got the error for the above code snippet

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-10-dbd95bfa64b9> in <module>()
      4 decode_image = ("trademark.jpg")
      5 
----> 6 result = decode(decode_image)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pyzbar/pyzbar.py in _pixel_data(image)
    145     else:
    146         # image should be a tuple (pixels, width, height)
--> 147         pixels, width, height = image
    148 
    149         # Check dimensions

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

How can I debug the code?

Comment: According to error you have to pass instead of `("trademark.jpg")` something like `(numpy_array, 123, 456)` where last two numbers are width and height and first `numpy_array` is array with pixels.

Comment: Can you share the source on which you're basing your implicit claim that `decode()` accepts a single string parameter? Seems [the documentation on GitHub](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/) does not mention this method signature - all I can find there is regarding passing an instance of `PIL.Image`, `numpy.ndarray`, or a tuple (as @Arty mentioned).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using PIL to open the image, as that is, what `pyzbar` [is designed for](https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/#example-usage):

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open("trademark.jpg")
result = decode(img)
```